# OpenCV opening laptop webcam not phone camera

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, wampserver

I am using the python script for face verification purpose. It is working fine on my computer and running fine with wamp server. I have allowed external access to my wamp server so I am able to access my localhost on my mobile as well. 
When i use my script on computer it fires the webcam and captures my image and updates the database(which is correct)

Now the problem is whenever i run the same script on my mobile device by accessing the ip address for my localhost it opens the computer webcam Not my phone camera to capture my image.

I want the script to capture the image from whichever device i am accessing it.

Link to get [haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml)

This Script is modified version of code posted on github by [nazmiasri95](https://github.com/nazmiasri95/Face-Recognition) and here is the [original code](https://github.com/nazmiasri95/Face-Recognition)

Here is my python code

```
#!C:\Users\Gurminder\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe
print("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
# Import OpenCV2 for image processing
import cv2
import mysql.connector
import numpy as np
import os 
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', host='localhost', 
database='faceapi')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

def assure_path_exists(path):
dir = os.path.dirname(path)
if not os.path.exists(dir):
    os.makedirs(dir)

# Create Local Binary Patterns Histograms for face recognization
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()

assure_path_exists("trainer/")

# Load the trained mode
recognizer.read('trainer/trainer.yml')

# Load prebuilt model for Frontal Face
cascadePath = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"

# Create classifier from prebuilt model
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascadePath);

# Set the font style
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

# Initialize and start the video frame capture

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # capturing from webcam (0) in args

# Loop
while True:
# Read the video frame
ret, im =cam.read()

# Convert the captured frame into grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Get all face from the video frame
faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.2,5)

# For each face in faces
for(x,y,w,h) in faces:

    # Create rectangle around the face
    cv2.rectangle(im, (x-20,y-20), (x+w+20,y+h+20), (0,255,0), 4)

    # Recognize the face belongs to which ID
    Id, confidence = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])

    # Check the ID if exist 
    if(Id == 1):

        confi = round(100 - confidence, 1)

        cursor.execute("insert into getmax (confident) values ('%s')" % (confi))



    elif(Id ==2):
        Id = "Swaran {0:.2f}%".format(round(100 - confidence, 2))

    # Put text describe who is in the picture
    cv2.rectangle(im, (x-22,y-90), (x+w+22, y-22), (0,255,0), -1)
    cv2.putText(im, str(confi), (x,y-40), font, 1, (255,255,255), 3)

    # For gray window
    cv2.rectangle(gray, (x-22,y-90), (x+w+22, y-22), (0,255,0), -1)
    cv2.putText(gray, str(confi), (x,y-40), font, 1, (255,255,255), 3)



cv2.imshow('gray',gray)
#cv2.imshow('Live Camera Capturing',im) 

# If 'q' is pressed, close program
if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

# Stop the camera
cam.release()

# Close all windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: try 
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

Comment: `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` means use the default webcam ie cam of Laptop. If you want to connect to the Android Phone camera you have to install `IP Webcam App` on you device